Coordinate transformation matrix for Robot configuration from Cox's Intro to Computational Algebraic Geometry
I'm stuck at understanding the basic configuration representation of a planer robot example. In Example 1 of Page 299, the book shows that the following $A_1$ represents the transformation of $(x_2, y_2)$ coordinates for the revolute joint 2 to $(x_1, y_1)$ coordinates for the revolute joint 1.
$$ A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta_1 & -\sin \theta_1 & 0 \\
\sin \theta_1 & \cos \theta_1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} $$
I understood that this is a composition of the rotation and the translation to bring the origin of Revolute joint 2 back to Revolute joint 1 (w/h length $l_1$) as follows;
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_i \\
y_i \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta_i & -\sin \theta_i & l_i \\
\sin \theta_i & \cos \theta_i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{i+1} \\
y_{i+1} \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
=
A_i \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{i+1} \\
y_{i+1} \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Thus, $A_1$ of Example 1 appears to be missing $l_1$ in the last column, meaning, following the above presented formula I thought the right $A_1$ in Example 1 should be;
$$ A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta_1 & -\sin \theta_1 & l_1 \\
\sin \theta_1 & \cos \theta_1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} $$
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks!
Screenshot of Book

